# Discrete Laplace transform. Analogy to change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

Assume $$f=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} c_k\cdot E^{k}$$
where the vector $E^k$ is $$E^k = (e^{2 \pi i k\cdot M}(0),e^{2 \pi i k\cdot M}(1),\cdots,e^{2 \pi i k\cdot M}(N-1))$$ (M is a constant and e represents the exponential function).

If we compute the inner product  $f\cdot E^k$ we obtain $N\cdot c_k$.

So we change the basis in which we represent $f$ (from values at different points to "a combination of the vectors $E^k, k=\overline{0,N-1}$").

This is what the discrete Fourier transform does, correct?

Is there a similar explanation for the Laplace transform?

Considering that $$L(f'(t)) = sL(f(t))$$
and $$L(\int_0^tf(t)\cdot dt) = \frac1sL(f(t))$$
the Laplace transform has something to do with the coefficients of f expressed in the new basis ($E^k, k=\overline{0,N-1}$),  no?

Comment: You are aware that you compare a discrete transform with a continuous (or integral) transform?

Comment: Yes, I am. I know that there is a discrete Laplace equivalent transform, the Z-transform. I thought the analogy of "changing the basis" could be extended to the discrete Laplace transform. But first, did I understand correctly what the discrete Fourier transform does?

Answer (score 1):

First yes, the discrete Fourier transform can be formulated in that way, as transformation between the coefficient sequence of a polynomial and the value tuple of an equidistant sample point set on the unit circle.

For the Z-transform, as the discrete Laplace transform, things are different, since it transforms a sequence into a formal power series which is, as a data structure, still the same sequence.

Comment: The fact that the transform of the derivative has the same result as the original function, but multiplied with the "point where the transform is evaluated" made me believe that it had something to do with writing the function using exponentials.